# Rename webpack/gatsby chunkmapping strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gatsby

When building our production app in Gatsby, I see something like this:

```
window.___chunkMapping={
  "app":[],
  "component---src-templates-page-tsx":[],
  "component---src-templates-pages-newsletter-tsx":[]
}
```

Is it possible to hash these paths instead of printing them out? We don‘t want to expose too much from what is happening in the back.

I tried setting these configs in webpack:

```
output: {
  filename: `[chunkhash:2][contenthash:5].js`,
  chunkFilename: `[chunkhash:2][contenthash:5].js`,
},
```

And it successfully hashes `.js` files but not the template paths.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I upvoted this question when I first saw it, I think it's definitely should be done in production build.

Unfortunately, `componentChunkName` (the template path in question) is generated by Gatsby in `createPage` & not handled by webpack.

The code that generates `componentChunkName` is over here: [github](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/src/utils/js-chunk-names.js#L12)

I tried to modify the code as follow:

```
    const { kebabCase } = require(`lodash`)
    const path = require(`path`)
+   const uuidv5 = require(`uuid/v5`)
    const { store } = require(`../redux`)

    const generateComponentChunkName = componentPath => {
      const program = store.getState().program
      let directory = `/`
      if (program && program.directory) {
        directory = program.directory
      }
      const name = path.relative(directory, componentPath)

-     return `component---${kebabCase(name)}`
+     return process.env.NODE_ENV === `production`
+       ? `component---${uuidv5(name, uuidv5.URL)}`
+       : `component---${kebabCase(name)}`
    }

    exports.generateComponentChunkName = generateComponentChunkName
```

This successfully hides all the component names in production build:

```
app: Array [ "/app-e593b3d93932ed3a0363.js" ]
"component---11d478fe-6a55-579c-becf-625ab1e57cf4": Array [ "/component---11d478fe-6a55-579c-becf-625ab1e57cf4-76c90ae50035c52657a0.js" ]
"component---15c76861-b723-5e0a-823c-b6832aeeb0a0": Array [ "/component---15c76861-b723-5e0a-823c-b6832aeeb0a0-18eb457ba6c147e1b31b.js" ]
...
```

None of the local unit tests failed, my clicking-around-until-something-breaks test also hasn't yielded any errors. I might submit a PR later today to see if the maintainers have some insights on why this is not a good idea.

**Edit**: I opened an issue instead: [github](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/18791), you can subscribe to the issue to see how it resolves.